# "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection cannot be cast to smartdatabase.Connection" anyone got any idea why?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, classcastexception

I am 100% sure my connection name is correct, "smartdatabase" is the package in which this code exists and "SmartData" is my embedded database within NetBeans IDE 8.2 (I believe it is a Derby database).

```
package smartdatabase;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;

public class Connection {

    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    public Connection() {

    }

    public void getStudents() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            conn = (Connection) 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SmartData;create=true;", "root", "The 
password");
        `    `String sql;
            sql = "SELECT Firstname, Surname FROM tblStudents";
            ResultS``et rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String Firstname = rs.getString("FirstName");
                String Surname = rs.getString("Surname");
                System.out.println(Firstname + "    " + Surname);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (`Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a class Named `Connection` in your `smartdatabase` package.
This class is used instead of `java.sql.Connection`
By default the compiler resolves `Connection` from the same package.

Try renaming that class or use the fully qualified name (`java.sql.Connection`) instead of just Connection:

```
private java.sql.Connection conn = null;
```